# Can exceptions be caught from both a try and except block with one except statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

In Python, can an exception be caught from an exception, and from the original try, with the same except statement?

For example, in the following code:

```
try:
    risky_operation() # This could raise a or b, or it could work
except a:
    simple_operation() # This could raise b, or it could work
except b:
    guaranteed_operation() # This will always work
```

Would `guaranteed_operation()` be called if `risky_operation()` raised `b`? Or would I have to do:

```
try:
    risky_operation() # This could raise a or b, or it could work
except a:
    try:
        simple_operation() # This could raise b, or it could work
    except b:
        guaranteed_operation() # This will always work
except b:
    guaranteed_operation() # This will always work
```

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: @C.B. That seems similar, however `a = this_variable_doesnt_exist` can't raise `ZeroDivisionError`

Comment: `Would guaranteed_operation() be called if risky_operation() raised b?` - No. Exceptions raised in `except` blocks will not be handled by other `except` blocks correspond to the `try` block.

Comment: @thefourtheye That answers my question, thanks